# MS Access using VBA to compare 2 recordsets not in the same order

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to write a function that compares the "Pack_Number" fields in two recordsets. My code works fine if they are in numerical order but if pack numbers are added out of order my code doesn't work right and won't recognize that the pack numbers exist.

My Code:

```
Function Validation()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsm As DAO.Recordset
        
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("RetailEntry")
Set rsm = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MasterQuery")

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Validate offers have not mailed
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True

  If rsm.RecordCount = 0 Or rs.Fields("Pack_Number") <> rsm.Fields("Pack_Number") Then
    MsgBox ("All prefixes have mailed for Pack Number " & rs.Fields("Pack_Number") & " If you wish to submit an In-season Markdown Request " _
    & "please exit the tool, and submit your request using the In-Season Markdown request file in the CID Request folder")
    Exit Function
  
rs.MoveNext
rsm.MoveNext
Loop
End If

End Function
```

What I'm trying to do is just have it verify that the pack number they entered from RetailEntry is appearing in the MasterQuery if it is then pass else fail and msgbox pops up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to check that ALL pack numbers in one table are in another table? Sounds like a FindUnmatched query. Access has a query wizard for that. Why do you have two tables with same data?

Comment: Yeah I realized I just need an unmatched query and then just run a check on record count >=1 for the query. The reason I have two tables with the same data is cause one is for data entry the other is tied to a query that looks up data from a sql table. Thanks for the response!